# How do I delete a Workflow Manager 1.0 child scope with permissions messed up?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013, administration, workflow-foundation-4.5, workflow-manager-1.x

I have Workflow Manager installation with an "OAuthS2SSecurityConfiguration" applied to the child workflows that I want to delete.

When I run any of the commands below, I get an "internal server error".  Since I see nothing in the EventLogs or local logs, I can only assume that this is an authentication issues (I have deleted workflows in the past with no issue.)

```
var dcli = new WorkflowManagementClient("http://host:port/PubSubActivitiesSample")

dcli.Activities.Delete()
dcli.Workflows.Delete()
dcli.CurrentScope.Delete()
```

I've also tried overwriting the workflow with a null security configuration.  I get an internal HTTP error on that too.

Finally I ran the following powershell command:

```
remove-wfscope -ScopeURI http://myhost:12291/PubSubActivitiesSample
```

I get an internal server error for this as well:

> Remove-WFScope: An internal error occurred.  For more details please see the server logs.  HTTP headers received from the server: ...

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?